# Python: strip function definition using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am a very beginner of programming and reading the book "Automate the boring stuff with Python'. In Chapter 7, there is a project practice: the regex version of strip(). My code below does not work (I use Python 3.6.1). Could anyone help?

```
import re

string = input("Enter a string to strip: ")
strip_chars = input("Enter the characters you want to be stripped: ")

def strip_fn(string, strip_chars):
    if strip_chars == '':
        blank_start_end_regex = re.compile(r'^(\s)+|(\s)+$')
        stripped_string = blank_start_end_regex.sub('', string)
        print(stripped_string)
    else:
        strip_chars_start_end_regex = re.compile(r'^(strip_chars)*|(strip_chars)*$')
        stripped_string = strip_chars_start_end_regex.sub('', string)
        print(stripped_string)
```

Comment: Does not work how, and for what input?

Comment: `r'^(strip_chars)*|(strip_chars)*$'` -> `r'^[{0}]+|[{0}]+$'.format("".join([re.escape(x) for x in strip_chars]))`. Also, remove the unnecessary `(` and `)` in `r'^(\s)+|(\s)+$'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use re.sub to substitute the characters in the start or end.
Let us say if the char is 'x'

```
re.sub(r'^x+', "", string)
re.sub(r'x+$', "", string)
```

The first line as lstrip and the second as rstrip
This just looks simpler.

Answer (score 0):

When using `r'^(strip_chars)*|(strip_chars)*$'` string literal, the `strip_chars` is not interpolated, i.e. it is treated as a part of the string. You need to pass it as a variable to the regex. However, just passing it in the current form would result in a "corrupt" regex because `(...)` in a regex is a *grouping* construct, while you want to match a single char from the define set of chars stored in the `strip_chars` variable.

You could just wrap the string with a pair of `[` and `]` to create a character class, but if the variable contains, say `z-a`, it would make the resulting pattern invalid. You also need to escape each char to play it safe.

Replace

```
r'^(strip_chars)*|(strip_chars)*$'
```

with

```
r'^[{0}]+|[{0}]+$'.format("".join([re.escape(x) for x in strip_chars]))
```

I advise to replace `*` (*zero or more occurrences*) with `+` (*one or more occurrences*) quantifier because in most cases, when we want to remove something, we need to match at least 1 occurrence of the unnecessary string(s).

Also, you may replace `r'^(\s)+|(\s)+$'` with `r'^\s+|\s+$'` since the repeated capturing groups will keep on re-writing group values upon each iteration slightly hampering the regex execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! python
# Regex Version of Strip()
import re
def RegexStrip(mainString,charsToBeRemoved=None):
    if(charsToBeRemoved!=None):
        regex=re.compile(r'[%s]'%charsToBeRemoved)#Interesting TO NOTE
        return regex.sub('',mainString)
    else:
        regex=re.compile(r'^\s+')
        regex1=re.compile(r'$\s+')
        newString=regex1.sub('',mainString)
        newString=regex.sub('',newString)
        return newString

Str='   hello3123my43name is antony    '
print(RegexStrip(Str))
```

Maybe this could help, it can be further simplified of course.